# Choosing the best concurrency list in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

My thread pool has a fixed number of threads. These threads need to **write** and **read** from a shared list frequently.

So, which data structure (it better be a List, must be monitor-free) in `java.util.concurrent` package is best in this case?

Comment: That depends what you want to do with the collection.  See [my blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/11/one-of-most-useful-additions-to.html) (although it's about .Net, the concepts are the same).  You are unlikely to be able to write correct thread-safe code with a `List`.

Comment: Now, I am using *CopyOnWriteArrayList*, but *ConcurrentModificationException* exception is still thrown occasionally.

Comment: Please include more information about what you're doing with the collection so people can answer better, otherwise it's just a guess.

Comment: The `ConcurrentModificationException` might not come from a synchronization problem; it also arises for example in a for-loop over a collection where you try to remove an element from the collection.

Comment: I know it is not part of the package, but has someone tried `Vector`?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

> had better be `List`

The *only* `List` implementation in `java.util.concurrent` is [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). There's also the option of a synchronized list as Travis Webb mentions.

That said, are you sure you need it to be a `List`? There are a lot more options for concurrent `Queue`s and `Map`s (and you can make `Set`s from `Map`s), and those structures tend to make the most sense for many of the types of things you want to do with a shared data structure.

For queues, you have a huge number of options and which is most appropriate depends on how you need to use it:

- [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)
- [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)
- [LinkedBlockingDeque](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html)
- [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)
- [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html)
- [SynchronousQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html)
- [DelayQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html)

Comment: `CopyOnWriteArrayList` has the disadvantage of being very expensive on write (but cheap for reads) If you are doing lots of writes you are better off with a synchronized List or a queue.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, generally you'd want a data-structure to be thread safe only if there are operations that will change the data or add/remove data. So unless you need to change the data in the "List" via some "set" method call, then the only other operation which is the add/remove operations are easily handled by a Queue data-structure (and it is also a best practice, unless of course if there is a need for the exception).

Answer (score 101):

Any Java collection can be made to be Thread-safe like so:

`List newList = Collections.synchronizedList(oldList);`

Or to create a brand new thread-safe list:

`List newList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)

Comment: *For this reason, you'll find no list implementations in java.util.concurrent* -- Uhm, there is a `ConcurrentHashMap` even though there is a `Collections.synchronizedMap` method.

Comment: Read the Javadocs on `ConcurrentHashMap`. The details of the synchronization implementation are different. using the `synchronized` methods in `Collections` basically just wraps the class in a Java monitor. `ConcurrentHashMap` uses more clever concurrency features.

Comment: Yep. Still, it makes your last sentence sort of invalid though.

Comment: To add onto aioobe's comment, and as ColinD mentioned there is the CopyOnWriteArrayList

Comment: If use a monitor, the performance of the program is really bad :-(

Comment: Just to add , iteration over newList is not thread safe. !!

Comment: @bluelurker wtf?! If iteration wasn't thread-safe than the list wasn't thread-safe at all. Hard to believe. I'll try it...

Comment: @bluelurker Thread safe if you "manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it" (java docs).    synchronized (list) {
      Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
  }

Answer (score 10):

If the size of the list if fixed, then you can use an [AtomicReferenceArray](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html). This would allow you to perform indexed updates to a slot. You could write a List view if needed.

Answer (score 9):

[`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) uses a lock-free queue (based off the newer [CAS instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap)).

Comment: ...which doesn't implement the `List` interface.

Comment: You should be able to wrap it in a List interface.  The performance benefits are worth it.  But you are right :-), it doesn't now.

Comment: eSniff, how would you go about implementing `List.set(int index, Object element)` with ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Comment: Most of the `List`-specific methods are either not going to be implementable using a `Queue` (add/set at a specific index, for example) or can sort of be implemented but will be inefficient (get from an index). So I don't think you could really wrap it. That said, I think the suggestion of a `Queue` is fine since the OP hasn't really explained why they need a `List`.

Comment: @ColinD that's the answer I was going for.  There's good reasons why the CLQ cannot be wrapped in a List.  Though I agree, cannot rule out the Queue interface.

Comment: Yea, I should have just keep my mouth shut and not answered without thinking about it...  You are both right wrapping list would just be ugly.   Upvote for all you guys for smacking me around :-).

Comment: ❗️ Worth noting that: _"Beware that, unlike in most collections, the size method is NOT a constant-time operation. Because of the asynchronous nature of these queues, determining the current number of elements requires a traversal of the elements."_

Comment: Yes, size() operation on ConcurrentLinkedQueue is cpu inefficient.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look at [ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList.htm) written by Doug Lea based on Paul Martin's "A Practical Lock-Free Doubly-Linked List". It does not implement the java.util.List interface, but offers most methods you would use in a List.

According to the javadoc:

> A concurrent linked-list implementation of a Deque
>   (double-ended queue). Concurrent insertion, removal, and access
>   operations execute safely across multiple threads. Iterators are
>   *weakly consistent*, returning elements reflecting the state of
>   the deque at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. They
>   do *not* throw ConcurrentModificationException, and may
>   proceed concurrently with other operations.

Answer (score 3):

If set is sufficient, [ConcurrentSkipListSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) might be used.
(Its implementation is based on [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) which implements a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).)

The expected average time cost is log(n) for the contains, add, and remove operations; the size method is not a constant-time operation.

Comment: But it is set not list. you cant add objects having same hashcod emultiple.

Comment: That is why I wrote: "If set is sufficient..."