# How to fix Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 1

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin, arraylist

Kotlin program snippet:

```
fun peek() = if (!elements.isEmpty() && elements.size > 0) elements[0] else null
```

It works great, but sometimes I get a firebase crash report:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 1
> java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:437)
> bigmick.ghu.util.Queue.peek (Queue.kt:17)

For me it sounds crazy: the list's size is 1, also the first (existing) element can be referred by index=0.

As far as I know it should work. But sometimes it does not.

Comment: seems more like kotlin problem than java problem

Comment: Can multiple threads access the list?

Comment: yes, more threads (kotlin dispatchers) can access the list

Answer (score 4):

The ArrayList class is not thread safe. When a thread makes a change at the same time another thread calls your method, unexpected and seemingly impossible things can happen.

A possible fix is to make it impossible for two threads to call methods of the list at the same time ("mutual exclusion"). This is easily achieved with Collections.synchronizedList

```
elements = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())
```

If you read elements from the list a lot more than you write, an alternative is to use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead of ArrayList

I see that you're using this code from a class called queue. In that case you may want to use an actual queue data structure instead of a list, and the standard library has many options you can choose from, depending on what behavior you want. See this question for example [Choosing the best concurrency list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203864/choosing-the-best-concurrency-list-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for your clean explanation and recommendations.
I guess, Collections.synchronizedList will be my friend.