# Is it necessary to add synchronized to my code?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, synchronized

the following code sometimes generates NullPointerException Exception at   `ret.forEach(v -> System.out.println(v));` line.
I think I have to use synchronized block or Lock Interface to avoid this error.
Is it correct?
Please tell me some advice.

```
List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0, 10).parallel().forEach(i -> {            
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            try {
                System.out.println("stop" + i);
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ret.add(i);
    });         
    ret.forEach(v -> System.out.println(v));
```

Comment: You define `ret` after you use it in the `IntStream`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I amend to put List<Integer> ret at first line,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things here to comment:

1. You can't use `ret` before its declaration.
2. You are adding elements to an `ArrayList` in parallel. `ArrayList` is not threadsafe so you shouldn't use it there. Look at [Choosing the best concurrency list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203913/710162).
3. Finally, if you are using `streams`, its better to use a `map` and a `collect`. Something similar to this:

   ```
   IntStream.range(0, 10)
     .parallel()
     .map(i -> do_watever(i))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());;
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I'll see this URL. It is good to use your 3. from the viewpoint of thread-safe

Answer (score 2):

Basically yes: you modify an `ArrayList` from multiple threads. `ArrayList` is not thread-safe, so doing that can cause *any number* of issues (there is no single problem/exception that will always happen).

Null-values being present when they shouldn't be is one of the possible outcomes of using non-thread collections.

The best way to produce a list from a stream is therefore not to use `forEach` and explicitly add something to a list, but to use `map` and `collect`.

Comment: Thanks! You mean that I should replace ArrayList with map or collection in my code, don't you?

Comment: No, I am talking about using different methods on the `Stream`: instead of building the functionality of `Stream.collect` manually using `forEach`, you should use [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)).