# parallelStream().forEach giving inconsistent output

Tags: java, foreach, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have code like below,

```java
List<String> itemIdList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> linkedItemIds = new ArrayList<>();
items.parallelStream().forEach(item -> {
    itemIdList.add(item.getId());
    validateLinkedItemStatus(order, error);
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(error)) {
        //some db validation
        return;
    }
    linkedItemIds.add(item.getLinkedId());
});
```

I want to perform this task in parallel due to large number of items, but every time I execute this loop the itemIdList size is different for the same items. Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: `ArrayList.add` isn't thread safe.

Comment: To get an advantage out of the Stream API, you there is no way around learning about its various operations, including the idiomatic way to collect into a `List`, rather than using `forEach` to use it like an old loop. With `forEach`, you get into thread safety problems like the one in your question or performance problems if you try to kludge the thread safety problems or even both kind of problems at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by incorrect usage of side effects. [The Stream API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) explicitly discourage such usage:

> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.
> If the behavioral parameters do have side-effects, unless explicitly stated, there are no guarantees as to the visibility of those side-effects to other threads, nor are there any guarantees that different operations on the "same" element within the same stream pipeline are executed in the same thread.

What you can do, since you need `id` and optionally `linkedId`, is to use a wrapper object for the ids, before collecting.

```
public record IdWrapper(String id, String linkedId) {

  public IdWrapper(String id) {
    this(id, null);
  }
}
```

And add the linked id in the object conditionally.

```
List<IdWrapper> wrappers = items.parallelStream()
            .map(item -> {
              validateLinkedItemStatus(order, error);
              return CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(error) ? new IdWrapper(item.id()) : new IdWrapper(item.id(), item.linkedId());
            })
            .toList();//or collect(Collectors.toList()) depending on the exact scenario
```

If you really want/need to use the current `forEach()` approach, in order to get correct result, you need to make the lists you are mutating synchronized:

```
List<String> itemIdList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
List<String> linkedItemIds = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

This will however undermine the performance benefit you are trying to achieve with parallelism.

> If executed in parallel, the non-thread-safety of ArrayList would cause incorrect results, and adding needed synchronization would cause contention, undermining the benefit of parallelism.

As pointed out by Holger in comments another possible problem is that `forEach` does not guarantee to respect encounter order of the stream.

Comment: Using a synchronized list with `forEach` will not only cause performance problems. The result element order may not match the original encounter order of the source list. The fix would be to use `forEachOrdered` instead of `forEach` which would harm performance even more…

Comment: Another thing that should be mentioned: it’s dubious that neither `validateLinkedItemStatus(order, error);` nor the condition `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(error)` actually depend on `item`. This might be an indicator that there’s additional hidden state that’s unlikely to be thread safe. Of if that’s not the case, these operations shouldn’t be repeated for every `item`.

Answer (score 0):

Try synchronizing lists: itemIdList and linkedItemIds. It looks like a race problem. You can easily synchronize lists by using Collections.synchronizedList(list)

Good example of thread-safe data structures are in the following topic ([Choosing the best concurrency list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203864/choosing-the-best-concurrency-list-in-java))

Comment: This will work, but be aware that external synchronization will hurt the performance of parallel streams.